# Typescript doesn't allow to destructure non existing property with a default

Tags: typescript

I have two types, one that contains a property named amount, and another that does not.
I want to destructure that property from either one or the other providing a default value in case it does not exists (the type that does not contain it).
This is valid JS code, however typescript is complaining that such property does not exist in one of the types, which is correct, but that's what the default value is for.

Here is the code:

```
interface A {
  amount: number;
  name: string;
}

type notA = {
  name: string
}

const values = new Map<string, A>()
values.set('test', {name: 'test', amount: 0})
const defaultValue = {name: 'no-test'}

const { amount = 0 } = values.get('tust') || defaultValue

console.log(name, amount)
```

I understand that what typescript is trying to protect me from is that such property exists with an incorrect type, but that should not be possible to begin with.
This is probably because typescript doesn't have exact types and it will allow attaching extra props to types that doesn't define them so, how can I make the above compile?

Comment: look up "type guards" https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd be strongly inclined to refactor to something like the following:

```
const { amount } = values.get('tust') || { name: "no-test", amount: 0 };
```

since your intent is presumably that there should be a default value of type `A`, especially if you are going to use `0` as the default value for the `amount` property.

---

But, assuming you can't change it, I suggest giving `defaultValue` an explicitly annotated type.  When you let the compiler infer its type, it becomes `{name: string}`.  This type is correct as far as it goes, but it does not imply anything at all about the `amount` property (as you note, object types in TypeScript are not exact).  If you would like the compiler to understand that `defaultValue` may be missing an `amount` property, you need to annotate it as such a type.  For example:

```
interface MaybeA {
  amount?: number;
  name: string;
}
const defaultValue: MaybeA = { name: 'no-test' }
```

I've declared a `MaybeA` interface  which is a wider version of `A` where the `amount` property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), so its type is either `number` or `undefined`.  This, then, will work as desired:

```
const { amount = 0 } = values.get('tust') || defaultValue // no error
```

---

You could also instead write the type `NotA` which is definitely missing the `amount` property:

```
interface NotA {
  amount?: undefined;
  name: string;
}
const defaultValue: NotA = { name: 'no-test' }
const { amount = 0 } = values.get('tust') || defaultValue // also okay
```

And of course, nothing requires that you actually give names to these types, especially if you only use them once:

```
const defaultValue: { name: string, amount?: undefined } = { name: 'no-test' }
const { amount = 0 } = values.get('tust') || defaultValue // okay
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwC2A9gK7gBcyIphARtANy74hERUDOYUoA5sxwBfXKJwJiIbsgBucADakInZAF5qEAO7IAsnAAOAHm68QfADRoAfAAoAlLjmLlAOk4QwNgOSRuXyxjU7FQ+ymD+BCTkYFQADMhCDjhshMr6iCgA6gAWAJ4AcsRgmCzIElLFgURk4AlqsgpKnC58Ht5gpH52yAA+PZhBqVQARCDEALS+YMOW1dFxCYL45ZzE8hAu8sR8NnPgdoIiOLgpaRnIAApQxHTrhCV4ZZLSACYQ8KTyYABqjSjqgVOITGkzCXgSpRWlUiNWK6niQnqTiaLTaPk64W6fWQbw+X1+zmQAHoichoNcoJDnmsNlsdnswAdiaTYrgjid2Jx0khkAAxYAADwe+FAkFg5z0uQY6Gwj3wDIA-FQaPQmKVWMFkCZ+EsIY8oTj3nBPj8-lRJdL6oDNV4QVNwUdls9oQz6gikX9mq1POiur1+rjjfi-szkMQANZwXJssSnLnnfkCgBMwuQoug8B5hTAMvVMOiSuQ5FxoAgL11GqGWp4OtKjqeFUNeNNzio2fQAMGHGQtom9r1TsbVSitXhdXUyNc3vaGK8WIDRpNBKUoYjUZjx2SnO5KETAGZUwbA0uzQMgdXTBZ8+BC8X3qWXuOzza7WCBw3pMPYW6n5OvWiOj9bFj2DQkSTDSNo2EMQxCAA)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to deal with this situation. Here's quick way

```
const defaultValue = { name: 'no-test' } as A
```

Check link: [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgWwHsBXcALmRGPwCNoBuHSgiCgZzClAHNGBfLFjABPAA4oQhMOgC8mJiBbtOPLAKwJCIDsgBucADbEIbZHJAQA7sgCycUQB4OXENwA0aAHwAKAJRZ9IxMAOjYIMG8AckgOSI8MRXxWZGiTMDi8IlIwCgAGPn9NbTBkABMIeGIDMAA1Q2MzTETkyMkAWhj0vjxTVEEinQxMknBG3ORuuUDjNmDucKiwYljfZAAfNbKKuCra%20oh%20rTZCAwhgg0Jub2aPAhGwXyA)